# Transaction Interceptor is not invoked when I used saveOrUpdate in Controller

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

Background/ Concept :

I am trying to persist data to Mysql Database by using Hibernate(5.0.5.Final) + Spring(4.2.3.RELEASE).

DAO :

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,rollbackFor =
{Exception.class})
 public abstract class DaoImpl implements Dao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Override
public <T extends Entity> void saveOrUpdate(T entity) {
    if (entity.getId() == null || entity.getId() == 0) {
        create(entity);
    } else {
        update(entity);
    }
}
```

Service :

```
@Service("entityService")
public class EntityServiceImpl implements EntityService {
    .....
}
```

Tx configuration :

```
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

 <!-- Spring/Hibernate TransactionManager -->
 <bean id="transactionManager" 
 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mainDataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- the transactional advice  -->
<tx:advice id="defaultTxAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" propagation="SUPPORTS" isolation="DEFAULT" 
 read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="find*" propagation="SUPPORTS" isolation="DEFAULT" 
read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="list*" propagation="SUPPORTS" isolation="DEFAULT" 
read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="is*" propagation="SUPPORTS" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="check*" propagation="SUPPORTS" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="add*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="false"/>
        <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="false"/>
        <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="false"/>
        <tx:method name="delete*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="false"/>
        <tx:method name="remove*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="false"/>
        <tx:method name="change*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="false"/>
        <tx:method name="modify*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT" read-only="false"/>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="Exception"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="servicesConfig"
                  expression="execution(* com.example.service..*Service.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="servicesConfig" advice-ref="defaultTxAdvice"/>
</aop:config>
```

Web xml :

```
   <filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Problem :

1. I created Junit Test and call services (saveOrUpdate ) data to db. It was working (interceptor called & data saved ).
2. I called my service to update data in controller and it was not working ( interceptor is not called & data is not saved).

The unit test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:application-main-context.xml")
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private UserHistoryService entityService;

    @Test
    public void testSaveNewKeyword(){
        entityService.saveKeyWord("SRD");
        entityService.updateScroing("text", "SRD");
    }

}
```

Controller code which can update data into database

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {     

@Autowired
private UserHistoryService entityService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/rd/search/result/{base}/{page}")
public String rdSearchResult(Model model, @PathVariable("base") String base, 
@PathVariable("page") int page,
        @ModelAttribute("searchDataModel") SearchDataModel searchDataModel) 
 {
    entityService.saveKeyWord("SRD");
    entityService.updateScroing("text", "SRD");
 }
}
```

I tried to debug and observed the different between these two. 
I run the test in Junit I saw that Transaction Interceptor was called. 
But I run the web app, I didn't see transaction interceptor calling.

Comment: How did you declare the entityService in the controller? I hope you used @Autowired there as-well?

Comment: Of course! I used @Autowired

Comment: Sure, was just checking. If the test is going through the interceptor, then another likely cause is that the web-app isn't loading the "DAO Context" that you mentioned. Can you please provide the entire spring context config for the app?

Comment: Let me guess... Both a `ContextLoaderListener` and a `DispatcherServlet` in your `web.xml`. Both loading an application context fie containing the same `<context:component-scan />` (or at least covering the same packages).

Comment: @AshutoshA, It is too long content. I was not allowed to post. could u please tell me which specific spring config path u want to see?

Comment: @M.Deinum, Both a ContextLoaderListener and DispatcherServlet in my web.xml. and it was in the same packages.

Comment: Read my comment again. Your configurations for both things probably contains `<context:component-scan />` for the same packages leading to 2 instances one proxied with transactions (and pretty useless because it will not be used) and one not proxied without transactions that will be used.

Comment: @M.Deinum, You are right . I already solved that problem. Thank you so much .

Comment: Good catch, @M.Deinum! One thing I didn't understand is -  why would only one of them be proxied?

Comment: Because Spring AOP only applies to the application context it is defined/loaded in. In this case I suspect that is the one created by the `ContextLoaderListener` and not the one read/created by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!